# How to drop a index row from multiindex dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

**DataFrame :df**

```
None  | A  B   col1  col1   col2   col2
X     |         v1    v2     v1     v2
---------------------------------------
0     | e1 f1   12   "def"   65    "pqr"
1     | e1 f2   23   "def"   20    "pqr" 
2     | e1 f3   0    "def"   91    "pqr"
3     | e2 f1   76   "def"   3     "pqr"
4     | e2 f2   89   "def"   33    "pqr"
```

Need to **remove** the row of "**X**". How I can achieve that?

Note -I also did not want col1 - v2 and col2-v2
for that code below was helpful -
df.drop("v2",axis=1,level=1)

Comment: Try [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html#pandas-dataframe-droplevel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer -

```
df.droplevel("X",axis=1)
```